# Google maps api license

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3

I am making a very small application which uses `google maps api`. I have a list of **starting address** and **destination address**. My application will calculate the **route distance**. I am **not** showing the Map on my application because this will use a considerable amount of bandwidth and slow the application. I am just using the distance value I get from the xml response.

I want to confirm that I am not breaking any license terms of google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

" I am not showing the Map "

I believe that is a violation of the user agreement.

[Here is the link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

Relevant text:

> Use of the Distance Matrix API must relate to the display of
>   information on a Google Map; for example, to determine
>   origin-destination pairs that fall within a specific driving time from
>   one another, before requesting and displaying those destinations on a
>   map. Use of the service in an application that doesn't display a
>   Google map is prohibited.

Edit:  On a side note, kudos to you for checking for violations before just doing something.  The world needs more devs like you.